# Django Admin redirects not working 

Tags: django, redirect, django-admin

I am using the latest checkout of the django trunk - when I am in the admin on the "change" page for an object/item, there is a nice little link that says "view on site".

The link points to a url such as:

```
http://example.com:8888/admin/r/22/15/
```

However, when I click on that link (or enter that link into my browser) I get redirected to:

```
http://example.com:8888//example.com:8888/video/15
```

Which isn't a valid url - but it's really, really close ... the same is happening when I try to `get_absolute_url` for a comment.  I get the short little redirect but it doesn't take me to the right page.

Any ideas why this is happening?

#### Additional Info (edit):

- have tried with 1.1.1 (same problem)
- I have one site listed under `sites` which is 'http://example.com:8888'

I thought maybe it had to do with the port number at the end - but what is strange is the my object's `get_absolute_url` works without a hitch.

I think the problem is coming from [`django.contrib.contenttypes.views.shortcut`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/contenttypes/views.py) which is doing some funny appending business to handle cross-site things ... which I don't quite understand.

#### get_absolute_url (for objects)

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('video_detail', [str(self.id)])
```

Comment: What are your settings in the `sites` application in the django admin?

Comment: Does this issue occur when you are running on the released version 1.1.1?  Do you have a specific reason for running off of trunk.  I know it was recommended for a while, but now that Django is making "regular" releases, I find it is often easier to run against the latest stable version.

Comment: I have updated my question - thanks for the clarifying questions ... hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's going on. Could you post your `get_absolute_url` method for the object that's not working?

Comment: Yea - me either.  Smile.  I may move it to a temporary prodution server and see if it has to do with my dev setup or is problem with the code ... I added the `get_absolute_url` method above.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: my site's 'domain name' was listed as:

```
http://example.com
```

But the 'http' is what is throwing it off.  When I removed it and just listed it as:

```
example.com
```

It works.  I just have to update my email templates to include the 'http', I think ... unless django comes with a built in for adding that in its `sites` package.  Off to investigate ...